# How can I block all email from Facebook? 

Tags: macos, email, facebook

I don't have a Facebook account, but I get announcements from it whenever a friend of mine adds a new "friend". He says his system was hacked and he cannot prevent Facebook from sending announcements to me. How can I block all messages from Facebook? I'm running Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: What email client are you using?

Comment: Tell your "friend" to get his system un-hacked.

Comment: Are you sure the emails are actually from Facebook?

Answer (score 3):

Open the email and at the bottom there should be something like `Manage Emails from Facebook` or right click where it says sender (when you're in the inbox) and select mark all mail from this sender as junk and all emails from Facebook will automatically go to junk and self-delete in 10 days.

Answer (score 1):

Most ISPs have some sort of anti-spam measures in place, and many provide ways for you to black-list one or more domains of your choice. Your email client (if you have one) may also allow to set-up rules or filter to automatically reject messages or at least move them to a Junk or Trash folder.

Once when I got a message via Facebook from a friend asking me to join, I was given the option to opt-out of all future messages from them.

Answer (score 0):

Did your friend register his Facebook using your e-mail address? This is what it sounds like because you only receive updates if your e-mail address is associated with the Facebook account. If this is the case have your friend change the primary e-mail address on Facebook to one of his own. You can find instructions on how to do this on google.